# Filter in mySQL

Tags: mysql, join, nested

i have 2 questions that trouble me sometime.

i have 2 tables.

and i want to use this table to run 2 different queries, i have tried many, but not success.

Query 1:
Filter out the employee who not taken AL(Annual Leave) before, but the status is currently pending AL only.

```
SELECT employee_id, leave_status, leave_type_id
FROM hs_hr_leave
WHERE leave_status =2
GROUP BY employee_id
```

above, the previous have Taken AL before also come out, but i don't know how to exclude previous taken AL employee.

The result should be 0002   AL  Pending & 0003    AL Pending.
0001   AL   Pending is not in list, because 0001 Taken AL before.

Query 2:
Want to filter out employee no Taken AL in records but have takes others leave like MC, no Pay,hospitalisation, maternity. The result only 0003 Miss C. Because Miss D & Miss E is totally no take any leave, so i don't need this result.

the table as like below:

Leave Table

```
employee_id|leave_type|status
0001       |AL        |Taken
0001       |MC        |Taken
0001       |AL        |Pending
0001       |AL        |Schedule
0002       |MC        |Pending
0002       |AL        |Pending
0003       |MC        |Pending
0003       |Others    |Taken
```

Employee Table

```
employee_id|employee_name|
0001       |Miss A       |
0002       |Miss B       |
0003       |Miss C       |
0004       |Miss D       |
0005       |Miss E       |
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you explain the terms "before" and "currently" ??
And create a sqlfiddle.com link with sample data. Then it will be useful....

Comment: I want the result only status = pending, and the employee no taken AL record in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query 1: Filter out the employee who not taken AL(Annual Leave) before, but the status is currently pending AL only.

```
SELECT d.id, status, type, name
FROM demo1 d INNER JOIN employee e ON e.id = d.id
WHERE 
status ='Pending' AND
type = 'AL' AND
d.id NOT IN(
SELECT id 
FROM demo1
WHERE type = 'AL' AND 
status ='Taken')
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24dad9/7)

Want to filter out employee no Taken AL before. The result only 0003 Miss C.

```
SELECT d.id, type, status, name
FROM demo1 d INNER JOIN employee e ON e.id = d.id
WHERE 
d.id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM demo1 WHERE type = 'AL') AND type <> 'Others'
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24dad9/2)

If any bug let me know, I am not clear about the conditions that you posted.

Comment: Hi Damodaran, Thanks for your answer, the first query work wonderful, is that result what i want,you are a genius, but the second query i run the SQL it return with no record. the Employee table store only employee details, then need to join with the leave table, just filter out which employee is no take AL in Leave table records,but have take others leave.I had amend my question, you may refer. Many thanks, appreciate that.

Comment: Check this query: 

SELECT DISTINCT d.id, type, status, name
FROM demo1 d INNER JOIN employee e ON e.id = d.id
WHERE 
 type <> 'AL' AND status = 'Taken' AND d.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM demo1 WHERE type = 'AL')